# Run-time error 91 with Access recordset; didn't used to get this error

Tags: vba, ms-access

I wrote a function to process a recordset in my Access database. The main method declares a recordset:
`Dim rs As Object`

I pass it into my function without initializing it first because that happens inside my function. Here is the function:

```
Function ProcessQuery(rs As Object, strQueryName As String, strFullFilepath As String, strWorksheetName As String, xlWorkbook As Object, blnHeaderRow As Boolean, blnExportToEMSSummary As Boolean, blnTieLine As Boolean)

    If rs.EOF = False Then   '--> this is the line that generates the error
        rs.MoveLast
        ProcessQuery = rs.RecordCount
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, strQueryName, acFormatXLSX, strFullFilepath, Autostart:=False
        ExportIt xlWorkbook, strWorksheetName, strQueryName, blnHeaderRow
    Else
        ProcessQuery = rs.RecordCount
    End If

End Function
```

The first line `If rs.EOF` is giving me a Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set. This just started happening to me today even though I've been working on this for a few days and all my testing with this function never generated this error before. Does anyone know why?

Also, I'm very new to Access VBA so I apologize if any of this is not best practice. This is the first time I've ever used recordsets. I'm also altering someone  else's code. They originally had 70 sections of code in the main macro that performed almost the same steps on 70 different queries. In each of these sections, their original code created the recordset from the query and exported it to an excel file, then passed the query name to another function called ExportIt where it was used to create a recordset again, export it to a specific sheet in an Excel template, and also compile an email with the information. So their flow is basically: main method > ExportIt

I figured I would save the space and write a method to replicate what was being done in each section of code. I was hoping that by declaring the recordset in the main method and passing it into the function (rather than passing the query name and just creating the recordset from scratch in the function), I would improve efficiency by not having the function reallocate space for a recordset every time it's called. Then I could alter the ExportIt function to accept the recordset itself rather than creating it again inside ExportIt. My flow is: main method > ProcessQuery > ExportIt (altered to accept rs)

Then I could just close the recordset in the main method when everything is done. Along those lines, I am also working on a different function to export the recordset to excel rather than using the DoCmd.OutputTo statement you see above. I thought if I did this, then I could use it for both tasks of exporting a recordset to an excel file and a specific worksheet in another excel file. I'm not familiar with DoCmd.OutputTo but I assumed it would re-run the query in order to export it. My whole goal here is to not run each query any more than is absolutely necessary because this macro takes a lot of time to run as is. But if there's a better way to do things, feel free to chime in!

Comment: For an uninitialized recordset, `rs.EOF` will always give this error (as well as any other method). This cannot work. -- Also you should declare `rs As DAO.Recordset`.

Comment: Oh my god, the problem was that my set statement got lost somewhere else with all the editing I've been doing. What a brain fart! Also, what's the advantage of using DAO.Recordset?

Comment: It gives you Intellisense (type `rs.` and get its methods), and better error checking at compile time. And makes code better readable (self documenting). Basically there is no reason not to. :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would be more robust.

```
Function ProcessQuery(rs As Object, strQueryName As String, strFullFilepath As String, strWorksheetName As String, xlWorkbook As Object, blnHeaderRow As Boolean, blnExportToEMSSummary As Boolean, blnTieLine As Boolean)

    If rs Is Nothing Then
        ProcessQuery = -1
    ElseIf Not rs.EOF Then   '--> this is the line that generates the error
        rs.MoveLast
        ProcessQuery = rs.RecordCount
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, strQueryName, acFormatXLSX, strFullFilepath, Autostart:=False
        ExportIt xlWorkbook, strWorksheetName, strQueryName, blnHeaderRow
    Else
        ProcessQuery = rs.RecordCount
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Perhaps. But include the comment from @Andre.